# ASP.NET: Shadowing Issues

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, polymorphism, shadowing

I have two classes in two separate libraries (one VB, one C#):

```
Public Class Item
    ...
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property TotalPrice() As String
    Get
        Return FormatCurrency(Price + SelectedOptionsTotal())
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

and

```
public class DerivedItem : Item {
    ...
   public new Decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get { return Price + OptionsPrice; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `DerivedItem.TotalPrice` shadows the `Item.TotalPrice` property. However, when trying to retrieve the `DerivedItem.TotalPrice` value, I'm still getting the base object's `TotalPrice` value.

Why is the `DerivedItem`'s property not being returned?

**EDIT**

I've actually found the problem! I am getting the wrong value in the JSON string being returned via AJAX. It turns out that the `TotalPrice` *is* being returned correctly, it's just being overwritten by the shadowed property call being made later in the JSON string. My new question, then, is how to I prevent the shadowed property from being serialized?

**(This question has been rescoped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570658/prevent-shadowed-property-from-getting-serialized))**

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on how you are instantiating the object.

For example:

```
DerivedItem i = new DerivedItem();
i.TotalPrice();
```

Will call the shadowed version.

However:

```
Item i = new DerivedItem();
i.TotalPrice();
```

Will actually call the base.

[Here's a nice explanation.](http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2008/01/15/118585.aspx)

Of course if at all possible I would avoid shadowing.... :-)

Comment: i'm instantiating the object from a webmethod parameter. see my comment on mystere man's answer

Comment: How is SomeMethod using item? Looks fun. VB Library with a C# Library to extend and then a VB AJAX call. :-)

Comment: yeah it's a fun project for sure... but i'm still having this problem. it's only happening when serializing the object to send back as a JSON string. it's really frustrating.

Comment: @jason I would bet the serializing / JSON library(ies) is likely the culprit of what you are seeing but of course this isn't much help to fix....

Comment: yeah i was thinking that too, but I'm using the built in serializer. check out the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570658/prevent-shadowed-property-from-getting-serialized

Answer (score 0):

Are you referecing TotalPrice from a reference to the base type?

```
Item item = new DerivedItem;
string s = item.TotalPrice;
```

Comment: no... the item is being bound via asmx web binding from an AJAX call. my sig looks like `Public SomeMethod(item As DerivedItem) As String`

Comment: How is SomeMethod using item?  Looks fun.  VB Library with a C# Library to extend and then a VB AJAX call. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does setting `<NonSerialized()>` attribute on the base class property work?

Comment: well that's the thing... i still want it to be serialized when the base class is used...